# AJAX CAll to weather API not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote an ajax GET to retrieve weather information but I keep getting an error. What is the issue here?

```js
function getTemperatureDetails(longitude, latitude) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    lat: latitude,
                    lon: longitude,
                    APPID: "c659eb709194683af915fba5e270c580"
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //Do Something to handle error
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        }
        getTemperatureDetails(35, 149);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems like a cross-origin issue.

Comment: you'd want `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather` - because as is, the request is looking for `./api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather` - relative to your current page - note, you wont have any luck at all if your page is `https`, because openweathermap don't do `https`

Comment: @DanPhilip - no, openweathermap allow CORS

Comment: OK...good to know!

Comment: it is a CORS issue please install nginx and configured it after that it i'll work. you have another temporary solution to check install chrome extension "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 -**

Add `http://` to the URL.`"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"` otherwise you're requesting to `http://yourserver.com/some-uri/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather` which obiously isn't the open wheather map API.

**2 -**

You're sending invalid longitude values (According to valid values of [openweathermap.org](http://openweathermap.org/current)), so either swap the parameters definition, or swap the values. I swapped the parameters definition since you usually use lat/lng and not lng/lat

[image]

Here's a working sample:

```js
function getTemperatureDetails(latitude, longitude) { //I put lat first
            $.ajax({
                // http:// added
                url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    lat: latitude,
                    lon: longitude,
                    APPID: "b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1"
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //Do Something to handle error
                    console.log(textStatus);
                }
            });
        }
        getTemperatureDetails(35, 149);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why would the order of the formal vars matter?

Comment: The order doesn't matter, but it seems he's sending longitude values in latitude values, that's why I made that observation.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Requesting to openWatherMap using latitude = 149 & longitude = 35 throws an error, while the opposite doesn't.

Comment: OK, makes sense now. Ignore me.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I ignored you, but added a reason for that in the answer :)

Comment: @coffeeak You're welcome, and just in case you should change your APPID if possible, since you posted it here, I don't know if they charge you but just in case...